# Why aren't my sets containing more than one element?- python 2.7

Tags: python, list, set, element

Ok, so I wrote some code and I want to compare two sets. However, the length will only return either 0 or 1, depending on whether I'm using two images or the same image. This is because my sets are being formed as only 1 element sets instead of mixing the numbers apart. For example, the sets read as [(a, b, c)] instead of [('a', 'b', 'c')].

Here's my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
N=0
colour=[]
colourfile=open('Green from RGB.txt', 'r')
for line in colourfile.readlines():
    colour.append([line])
colour_set=sorted(set(map(tuple, colour)))



def OneNumber(im): #Converts the pixels rgb to a single number.
    temp_im=im.astype('int32')
    r,g,b = temp_im[:,:,0], temp_im[:,:,1], temp_im[:,:,2]
    combo=r*1000000+g*1000+b
    return combo



while True:
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    start=time.time()
    while(cam.isOpened()):                  #Opens camera
        ret, im = cam.read()                #Takes screenshot
        #im=cv2.imread('filename.type')
        im=cv2.resize(im,(325,240))         #Resize to make it faster
        im= im.reshape(1,-1,3)
        im=OneNumber(im)               #Converts the pixels rgb to a singe number
        im_list=im.tolist()                 #Makes it into a list
        im_set=set(im_list[0])              #Makes set
        ColourCount= set(colour_set) & set(colour_set) #or set(im_set) for using/ comparing camera
        print len(ColourCount)
```

Also the text file I'm opening is written as:

```
126255104, 8192000, 249255254, 131078, 84181000, 213254156,
```

In a single, great big line.

So basically, how do I divide the numbers into different elements in the sets, im_set and colour_set?

Thanks

Comment: This is hard to follow. Please make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few bugs in your code.  It looks like you are reading all the colors into a single string.  You need to split the string instead if you want a set of colors:

```
for line in colourfile.readlines():
    temp_line = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]  ## create a temporary list, splitting on commas, and removing extra whitesapce
    colour.extend(temp_line)  ## don't put brackets around `line`, you add another "layer" of lists to the list
     ## also don't `append` a list with a list, use `extend()` instead
#colour_set=sorted(set(map(tuple, colour)))  ## I think you're trying to convert a string to a 3-tuple of rgb color values.  This is not how to do that
```

You have a serious problem with your rgb color representations: what is `131078`?  Is it (13, 10, 78), or (131, 0, 78), or (1, 31, 78)?  You need to change how those color strings are written to a file, because your format is ambiguous.  To keep it simple, why not write it to a file like this:

```
13 10 78
255 255 0
```

If you insist on encoding the rgb triples as a single string, then you *HAVE* to zero-pad all the values:

```
## for example
my_rgb = (13,10,78)
my_rgb_string = "%03d%03d%03d" % (r, g, b)  ## zero-pad to exactly 3 digit width
print(my_rgb_string)
>> 013010078
```

Another problem: you are intersecting a set with itself, instead of intersecting two different sets:

```
ColourCount= set(colour_set) & set(colour_set) #or set(im_set) for using/ comparing camera
```

should be something like:

```
ColourCount= set(colour_set) | im_set #or set(im_set) for using/ comparing camera
```

if you want to create a union of all the different colors in the image.

If you still have problems after fixing these issues, I would recommend you post a new question with the updated code.